# Get the exe full path of wcf service

Tags: wcf, reflection, firewall

I am creating a wpf application where it is going to be installed on several computers in the same network. The application is supposed to talk to other applications therefore I am implementing a WCF service in my application. Everything works great with no firewall. As a result I am just missing some code in order to add an exception to the firewall.

To add an exception to the firewall for a program I execute the following code in cmd (or in a process in c#)

> netsh firewall add allowedprogram "C:\users..etc\myProgram.exe" MyProgram ENABLE

the problem is that I don't know what exe is hosting my service!!!  I will like to find that out so that I can  add the firewall exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that my only option will be to open that port in the firewall. I think that is not secure at all. the way to do it is:

Remove it first in order to avoid having duplicates:

> netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Description Goes Here" dir=in protocol=TCP localport=8732

then add it:

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Description Goes Here" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8732

now everyone will be able to use that port to communicate...

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you set it up. It is possible to use WCF through an executable using named pipes. But, from the looks of it here you are hosting it through IIS. When you deploy, there will not be an "exe".

Instead, your project will generate a "dll". This dll will be loaded into the existing IIS process and run within an application pool. This application pool will run under the web server (IIS), and depending on your configuration will probably run under HTTP or HTTPS.

HTTP runs under port 80, and HTTPS runs under port 443 (SSL).

Comment: thanks for the help. I am not using IIS. I am using a WCF class library and the services start to run whenever I start my wpf application because I added a reference from my wpf application to my WCF class library

Comment: If you're not using IIS, you need to use a `ServiceHost` in an executable of your own to actually start the service. You seem to be referring to running the service in the [WCF Service Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363.aspx) from the debugger, which is not an option for a service in production.